# Navbar not working mobile

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, navbar

```
     <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="myNavbar">
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <img src="http://karinakozarova.me/Blog/pics/logo-kari.png" width = "90px"/>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right text-color">
                  <li><a class = "menu" href="\Blog\home.html">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a class = "menu" href="\Blog\posts.html">Posts</a></li>
                  <li><a class = "menu" href="\Blog\contact_info.html">Contact</a></li>
                  <li><a class = "menu" href="\Blog\about.html">About</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
  </nav>
```

The following code doesn't work on mobile, in another SO question I read that the data-target="myNavbar" so i did it but it's still not working.

Comment: Do you use the script too?

Comment: Which script do you mean?

Comment: The bootstrap javascript which handle this of course :) I see, the problem was solved. What was the problem?

Comment: Forgotten jquerry link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are giving `data-target` an ID ...You need to use `#` before the `id`

set

```
data-target="#myNavbar"
```

It should work now.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <img src="http://karinakozarova.me/Blog/pics/logo-kari.png" width = "90px"/>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right text-color">
                  <li><a class = "menu" href="\Blog\home.html">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a class = "menu" href="\Blog\posts.html">Posts</a></li>
                  <li><a class = "menu" href="\Blog\contact_info.html">Contact</a></li>
                  <li><a class = "menu" href="\Blog\about.html">About</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its working...make sure you have added css from bootstrap and script from jquery before script from bootstrap and if still not working do tell me i'll link the codepen

Comment: Can you please share it?

Comment: check out the snippet

Comment: glad to be of help:-)